# Unable to save data into database after clicking submit button using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I've created this code in PHP which includes a form. In this form the user can insert an announcement. To save the datas into database I've created this submit button with the value `POSTO`.

But when I fill the form and click the submit button nothing happens and the data is not saved into the database. A
lso if I put a wrong name of table it doesn't show error.

Here is my database: [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5iec.png)

Here is the PHP code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if( !($database=mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))||!(mysql_select_db("st_login",$database))  )
   print("Could not connect");


//postohen announcement
echo "Post announcement";
print("<form><p> <textarea  cols='40' rows='30'></textarea> </p>
  <input type='submit' name='njoftim' value='Posto'/></form>  ");


if(isset($_POST['njoftim'])){
$njoftim=$_POST['njoftim'];
  $query="INSERT INTO `njoftime` (njoftim) VALUES ('$njoftim')";
    if(!($result=mysql_query($query,$database)))
{
    print("Could not execute query");
    die (mysql_error());//ose error
}

   }

mysql_close($database);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at these: [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), 
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php), [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php). Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5 (and removed entirely in PHP 7) and you should [stop using them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) if you can,  [you are vulnerable to SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Please don't use the deprecated mysql_* functions. Use mysqli or pdo. Btw, your code is wide open for SQL injections. Always sanitize your inputs.

Comment: A form, with no method specified, will default to GET. You need to add the action as `action='post'` in the form tag

Comment: @RamRaider it's `method="post"`, `action` attribute specifies the place where input should be sent (the script path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly to the problem: you must specify the post method in your form: `<form method="POST">`, otherwise your `$_POST` superglobal would not be populated with the form values. Either this, or use `$_GET`, but `$_POST` is better.

- POST requests are never cached
- POST requests do not remain in the browser history
- POST requests cannot be bookmarked
- POST requests have no restrictions on data length

while GET requests should only be used to retrieve data.

Also, please note, that the `mysql` extension is deprecated, use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. It's safer.

And your code is also open to endless SQL injection possibilities - a way to `DROP DATABASE` for sure. So sanitize the input a user posts.